# Cs-cart 4 page loading but console shows 404

Tags: http-status-code-404, console.log, cs-cart

Evening...

Im building a customised ecommerce app using cs-cart 4.1.2 and have come across an issue, not an error but a strange behaviour...

I have replaced the render_location function in the index.tpl with a simple bit of logic to include a custom template based upon the dispatch value.

This has worked fine on all pages to date, until now... I have a custom template 'search.tpl' which is called when the dispatch route is custom_search.search. The page loads and the template displays as expected BUT in the console and response headers i see a 404 status..?

I have done a couple of things to try to work out what is causing this including adding a location of the same dispatch value to the layout in case the system needs this.

There is a frontend controller file which is being called so thats working, I have a template hook to replace the page title and that is being called so the system is definitely rendering the page as expected.

Has anyone come across this before?

Cheers,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

Right, so you don't waste your time on this, and to help others out with the same issue, I found the problem.

I modified the index.tpl file to call custom templates for every view so that I did not have to deal with the nightmarish templating system (only really a nightmare if your looking to heavily modify the front end). In doing this I removed the render_location function which renders all of the blocks / tpl files to generate the views. Despite removing this function the system still requires that you have the correct files in place, even though not used, in the addon.

So in the design > themes > theme_name > templates > addons >addon_name > views > addon_name you always need to have a tpl file with the same name as the second part of the dispatch call.

E.g for dispatch=addon_test.view you would need the following:
design > themes > theme_name > templates > addons > addon_test > views > addon_test > view.tpl